# Identity Server - Multiple users with different access levels on different accounts

Tags: oauth, openid-connect, identityserver3

My application is composed of an API layer which is accessable by presenting a Bearer Token, obtained from our Identity Server. Each of our API has a level of scopes that the token must contain in order to be invoked: this means, for example, that if you want to make the API call which "creates a product" you need a write access to products (i.e. the scope "products") while you may just need the scope "products_read" if you only want to retrieve them.

Scopes are bound into the token when you authenticate onto the ID server.

Now, I need this user to be able to perform different operations on different "workspaces". Each workspace administrator can set which permissions each user have. This is, in fact, linked to the scopes that each user will have when operating on that particular workspace.

Right now we have implemented that, if you are trying to access a different workspace, the API layer will check:

1. if your bearer token is valid (by validating it on the ID server)
2. if you are authorized to access that workspace
3. changing associated claims by removing the original "scopes" (set into the token by the ID server) and overwriting with those assigned by the administrator of that workspace

This somehow works, but it stinks because I don't want my application layer (API) to have this kind of responsability and the opportunity to tamper with the token. I want the ID server to handle it and, after the user tries to enter into a different workspace, it generates a new crafted bearer token with correct claims (so the API will just need to trust it).

What's the best approach in doing that? I'm digging into the "custom grant type": may this be the right approach?

Comment: I dont think conflating scopes with permissions is how oauth2 was designed. Specifically clients may even request spoces that users don't have access to yet. I think you need an entirely separate mechanism for access control rules.

Comment: @Evert, yes that was another point of though. But, in any case, where would you put this separate mechanism?

Comment: Not sure because I don't know IdentityServer, but if they don't have a mechanism I would presume you design your own data model for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Scopes are fixed at design time and the same for all users. I like your use of `products` and `products_read` - that is very standard.

When you need dynamic behaviour, implement claims, which depend on who the user is. In your case I would use a `workspaces` array claim. Since this is a key vaue for authorization, it should be added to access tokens at the time  of token issuance. Think in terms of your products scope being composed of claims.

It feels like workspaces and other permissions are part of your business data rather than your identity data. At the time of token issuance, IdentityServer should send identity attributes (eg subject claim) to an API endpoint you provide. which returns business attributes (workspaces). I believe in IdentityServer this is done via a [custom profile service](https://damienbod.com/2016/11/18/extending-identity-in-identityserver4-to-manage-users-in-asp-net-core/).

I'd try to avoid different tokens for different workspaces, since that will be awkward in terms of usability and code complexity. The standard way to do it would be to redirect the user each time.

Comment: Yes, scopes are fixed and I'm ok with that. Claims are already used for our users. Identity Server, after successful authentication, generates a token with claims in the form of "scope" as type and "scope name" as value. E.g., a user which enters with a granted "products" scope, will have an identity with a "scope: products" claim. What you say seems correct to me, but I'd need to return a claim like this: "workspace_a: [products]" "workspace_b: [products_read]" and then, when he tries to enter into workspace_b, I chage his scope claims, by taking them from the correct array. Is that ok?

Comment: I would have thought you just need to write code like in the IdentityWithAdditionalClaimsProfileService from the above link, to add .NET claims in a dynamic way. Then they become standard JSON fields in the JWT payload, which you can later access in the target API via the ClaimsPrincipal. When the user navigates workspaces. his claims stay in place, but if he accesses one he is not authorized for there is a forbidden error.

Comment: I got what you say. I'm using IdentityServer3 and I need the best is to implement a new custom Claims Provider (implementing IClaimsProvider), inheriting the default one and adding claims in the form "Workspace_X"  (where X is the Workspace ID) and with value containing all the granted permissions on that workspace. In this way, when a request is made to our API we can get, from the associated claims, if that particular workspace is enabled and which are the granted operations. What do you think about this approach?

Comment: Sounds like the same type of behaviour I was suggesting. At least add the main identity values. I would use a single array claim called workspaces, but anything similar is fine.